# Cannot understand behavior of STL map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have a STL map declared like this:

```
std::map< std::pair<int, int>, long long> m;
```

If I do:

```
m.insert( make_pair( make_pair(1,1), 1000ll ));
```

followed by:

```
cout << m[make_pair(1,1)] << endl;
```

it writes 0 at the terminal.

However:

```
m[make_pair(1,1)] = 1000ll;
```

works fine.

As I know, the first way of inserting elements in a map is the recommended one. 
What am I missing?

EDIT:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

long long max_partition(    vector<long long> numbers, int numbers_size, int partition_number, map<pair<int, int>, long long> &subproblems)
{
    long long v = subproblems[make_pair(numbers_size, partition_number)];
    if( v ){
        cout << "SP" << endl;
        return v;
    }

    if(partition_number == 1) {
        long long s = accumulate(numbers.begin(), numbers.begin() + numbers_size, 0ll);
        subproblems.insert(make_pair( make_pair(numbers_size, partition_number), s) ); 
        return s;
    }

    if(numbers_size == 0) {
        subproblems.insert(make_pair( make_pair(numbers_size, partition_number), numbers[0])); 
        return numbers[0];
    }

    long long max_p = 500 * 10000000l;

    for(int i = partition_number - 1; i < numbers_size; i++) {
        long long acc = accumulate(numbers.begin() + i, numbers.begin() + numbers_size, 0ll) ;  
        long long mp = max_partition(numbers, i, partition_number - 1, subproblems);
        max_p = min(max_p, max(mp, acc));
    }

    subproblems.insert(make_pair( make_pair(numbers_size, partition_number), max_p) ); 
    //subproblems[make_pair(numbers_size, partition_number)] = max_p;
    return max_p;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    map<pair<int, int>, long long> subproblems;
    long long arr[] = {50, 50, 50, 50, 50}; //, 40, 50};
    vector<long long> p(arr, arr + 5);
    max_partition(p, 5, 4, subproblems);

    map<pair<int, int>, long long>::iterator it;

    for(it = subproblems.begin(); it != subproblems.end(); it++)
        cout << "val: " << it->second << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably have something with that key before the call to `insert`. If you do exactly what you say you are doing, you will print `1000`.

Comment: I'd say [you're lying](http://ideone.com/bFvgPu).

Comment: [This does not seem to be the case](http://ideone.com/t60fAy). Please show your real code.

Comment: damn `1` and `l` so confusing

Comment: @MateiFlorescu Please post the `whole` routine instead :D

Comment: [This reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) might help alleviate the confusion.

Comment: http://ideone.com/kd6UJc

if one switches lines 35 with 36, the map will have different content. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but cannot see what.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Wrong, that is a mistake that I have seen before. The issue is quite real, and the answer can be summarized as: the call to `insert` cannot be used to *update* a value in the map.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Fair enough, and good crystal ball skills :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The beginning of your function already *inserts* the element into the map (`operator[]` will insert the element for you if it did not exist before):

```
long long v = subproblems[make_pair(numbers_size, partition_number)];
```

You later try to *insert* the element again with:

```
subproblems.insert(make_pair( make_pair(numbers_size, partition_number), max_p) );
```

But that insert fails, as the element already exists, and the contract of `std::map<>::insert` is that if it is already there it will be left untouched.

The first check seems to be attempting to test whether the element was present in the map before the call to this function, if that is the case, you can use `find`:

```
iterator it=subproblems.find(make_pair(numbers_size,partition_number));
if (it != subproblems.end()) {
   return it->second;
}
```

Although that will require a second lookup when you do the real `insert`. An alternative is to directly attempt the insert in the beginning, and using the result to test whether the element already existed and as the iterator to use:

```
pair<iterator,bool> r = subproblems.insert(
                           make_pair(make_pair(numbers_size,partition_number),0));
if (!r.second) {             // existed before
    return r.first->second;  // return that value
}
...
r.first->second = numbers[0]; // replaces the insert in your code
```